# What is the shortcut for opening MSDN page in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am thinking that there may be some shortcut for opening the related MSDN page for default c# methods classes etc.

Such like:

```
String variableName = "Variable";
```

press some shortcut while String focused and it opens:
[String Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: You mean pressing F1 when the function/type is highlighted?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the cursor on the keyword and press F1. You will be redirect to related MSDN page. Example in your case

`String variableName = "Variable";`

Put your cursor on `String` and press F1 you will be redirected to `MSDN` page of String documentation.